# Keycloak backchannel login with .NET core api?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, keycloak

According to this OpenID spec https://openid.net/specs/openid-client-initiated-backchannel-authentication-core-1_0.html

> OpenID Connect Client Initiated Backchannel Authentication Flow is an authentication flow like OpenID Connect. However, unlike OpenID Connect, there is direct Relying Party to OpenID Provider communication without redirects through the user's browser. This specification has the concept of a Consumption Device (on which the user interacts with the Relying Party) and an Authentication Device (on which the user authenticates with the OpenID Provider and grants consent). This specification allows a Relying Party that has an identifier for a user to obtain tokens from the OpenID Provider. The user starts the flow with the Relying Party at the Consumption Device, but authenticates and grants consent on the Authentication Device.

I'm trying to do the same with my .NET core api using Keycloak as the IdentityProvider. This is current working setup with **Authorization Code Flow**

```cs
var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationType = OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    ClientId = Application.Config.KeycloakConfig.Default.ClientId,
    Authority = Application.Config.KeycloakConfig.Default.Authority,
    RedirectUri = Application.Config.KeycloakConfig.Default.SiteManagementAuthRedirectUri,
    ClientSecret = Application.Config.KeycloakConfig.Default.ClientSecret,
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
    Scope = "openid",
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        IssuerValidator = (issuer, securityToken, validationParameters) =>
        {
            if (issuer != Application.Config.KeycloakConfig.Default.Authority)
                throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Invalid issuer");
            return issuer;
        },
        ValidAudience = Application.Config.KeycloakConfig.Default.ClientId
    },
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
    }
};

appBuilder.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
```

I managed to get the tokens using password grant as below

```
HTTP POST {{KeyCloakUrl}}/realms/My-Realms/protocol/openid-connect/token
{
   grant_type: "password",
   client_id: "Keycloak_client_id",
   client_secret: "***",
   username: "username i created in Keycloak",
   password: "***",
   response_type : "code id_token",
   scope: "openid"
}
```

Reponse:

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI***********",
  "expires_in": 300,
  "refresh_expires_in": 1800,
  "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJ********",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "id_token": "eyJhbG**********",
  "not-before-policy": 0,
  "session_state": "c2803e20-bc04-4a9c-9b1a-d1fd3dfd1f22",
  "scope": "openid email profile"
}
```

**Question**: Is it possible to manual make a POST request with `id_token` to the .NET core api to authenticate the requests and how to do it?